# Hibernate @Size validation on custom type

Tags: java, scala, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am starting to use Hibernate Validator project for bean validation.  The default annotations of min/max/size would be great to use on custom types.  I was wondering how do I add a type for validation?  I have seen how to create my own new validation, but don't see how to add types for existing validations.

Main reason I am looking into this is because of Scala.  I want @Size and @Min to work with scala's collections.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to use bean validation in my Scala project is to create a Java class with the annotations, and then use that Java class in my Scala code. If I find a better way, I'll update this answer.

**Update**

Apparently you can use bean validation in Scala.

Here is some discusson on using bean validation with Scala. I'm afraid it doesn't answer your question though:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/30628

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9709956  I use the following idea to get annotations to work with scala.